# What's the officially recommended way to create Wizards in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

VSCode's official documentation of [Extension Guidelines for WebViews](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-guidelines#webviews) currently discourages the use of WebViews for Wizards, as [quoted](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/92673914cede3dec8443a43e8db9aac6384b6d54/api/references/extension-guidelines.md#L177-L184) here below:

> Don't
>
> - Use for promotions (upgrades, sponsors, etc.)
> - Use for wizards
> - Open on every window
> - Open on extension updates (ask via a Notification instead)
> - Add functionality that is unrelated to the editor or workspace
> - Repeat existing functionality (Welcome page, Settings, configuration, etc.)

With the release of [VSCode's Webview UI Toolkit](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/10/11/webview-ui-toolkit) I was looking into using  them for WebView based Wizards, but because the documentation doesn't recommend this, I'd like to know if there's an official correct approach for wizards. I could not find anything in the official APIs and docs (hopefully I didn't missed it).

My current plan is to go against the recommendation if there's nothing else available.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a string search for "wizard" in [that same guideline document you did](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/92673914cede3dec8443a43e8db9aac6384b6d54/api/references/extension-guidelines.md#L177-L184), and there are *two* instances. You found the one saying not to use WebViews for wizards. [The other one says to use the multi-step pattern with Quick Picks for wizards](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/92673914cede3dec8443a43e8db9aac6384b6d54/api/references/extension-guidelines.md#quick-picks):

> [Quick Picks](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#quick-pick) are an easy way to perform actions and receive input from the user. This is helpful when selecting a configuration option, needing to filter content, or picking from a list of items.
>
> [image]
>
> *This made-up example shows all of the variations that a Quick Pick can contain. It can have items with icons, detail lines, and labels for indicating a default or current item. At the top, it shows the multi-step pattern with back, undo, and forward actions.*
>
> **Do**
>
> - [...]
> - Use the multi-step pattern for a series of inputs (like a wizard)
> - [...]